# Confused regarding add() method of a ListIterator in a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working my way through a university practical on LinkedLists. 
I am having difficulty understanding the add() method of an iterator traversing a LinkedList. Our lecturer has given us the code to implement this, so copying exactly from him:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    public LinkedList() {
        Node first = null;
    }

    class Node {
        public Object data;
        public Node next;
    }  

    class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator {

        public LinkedListIterator() {
            Node position = null;
            Node previous = null;
        }

        public void add (Object element) {
            if (position == null) {
                addFirst(element);
                current = first;
            } else {
                //1 Node newNode = new Node();
                //2 newNode.data = element;
                //3 newNode.next = current.next;
                //4 current.next = newNode;
                //5 current = newNode;
            }
            previous = current
        }
```

Note: I have deliberately not encapsulated the variables and have cut out excess code to save space. I'm aware it doesn't compile, but my question is more conceptual.

In the add method:
The if statement simply detects if the iterator's position is null, in which case it adds the element to the start of the LinkedList and sets the iterators position to this newly created node.

The else statement is confusing me though:
Lines 1 & 2: A new node is created and its data is set to the element parameter.
Line 3, the *next* variable of this new node is set to the current node's *next* node i.e. it is set to whatever is after the position of the node the Iterator is pointing at.
Line 4, the "next" of the node the Iterator is *currently* pointing at is changed to the newNode (effectively completing the insertion of the new node between two existing nodes).
Line 5, the Iterator's position is set to point at the newNode.

After the else statement, the previous node that the Iterator was pointing at is set to the current node.

Herein lies the problem - doing that effectively syncs up the position and the previous position of the iterator. I checked this through the Eclipse debugger. This renders the previous useless. However, I'm aware that you can't reverse traverse a LinkedList using the standard iterator anyway.

When I comment this line out, nothing seems to change. Is this line simply unnecessary or does it have some function that I'm not actually realising? (Another reason I am asking is because the reverse of this appears in our notes for the remove() method, which again doesn't seem to have a purpose.

**Edit: It appears this answer may be answered as my course develops. For now, I am moving the previous = current line to above the current = newNode line. This appears to keep all values separate.**

Comment: @Aubin It's actually a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which extends the regular `Iterator` interface and includes `add`, `set`, `hasPrevious`, and `previous` methods.

Comment: Ah, apologies - should have been more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract for [`ListIterator.add(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29) specifies that *a subsequent call to `next` would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to `previous` would return the new element*, that is the purpose of updating `previous` in the implementation of `add`.

Comment: But doing this syncs previous and current together, meaning that for the rest of the run of the program, they are set at the same thing. I think as others said on here it might be expanded upon in later lectures.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor probably gave you sample code that will be expanded upon later in the course.  It looks like the sample code includes parts that would support a doubly linked list in future.  Doubly linked list do allow reverse traversal of the list.    [See wikipedia for details.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

On a completely unrelated topic; I applaud you for actually trying to understand and comprehend what was given to you instead of just plug-and-chugging to get the assignment done.  That habit will serve you well in the future!

Comment: Thanks for this, it probably will be expanded later. And thanks for your kind words! We don't actually need to touch or amend the add method at all, I just want to know how everything works and when it's best to use arraylists, linkedlists etc.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me.  The `previous = current` assignment needs to happen *before* the `current = newNode` assignment.  Then `previous` would refer to the old `current`, and the new `current` would be the newly created node.

Comment: That's what I thought. I guess we'll expand on it later. Thanks for this